# C# XmlDocument.Load Issue

Tags: c#, xml, blazor

I plan to use XmlDocument.Load() when a user clicks on a file from an open window dialogue. I am testing it with a absolute path

`XmlDocument.Load("C:\\filename.xml");`

This errors out. Chrome Developer tools states it cannot find the file and it is looking for the file with the following form "/C:\filename.xml"

Obviously this won't work because for that preceding backslash. Is there a way to remove that or is there a better way to do what I am doing?

Comment: Is it client side Blazor? It has no access to whole file system.

Comment: Ah! That might explain it! It is client side I never thought about that but should have. Therefore I should probably have a server side working along side of this that handles this end of things, shouldn't I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT : Like Alexander said, this is caused by specific access rights. Your code is good.

In case of, use `@` for paths like that :

```
XmlDocument.Load(@"C:\filename.xml");
```

You won't be bothered by the number of `\`
especially if you use network paths like `\\192.168.1.x\SharedFolder`.

Comment: I tried that with no success. :(

Comment: @DaveK Your code is good, \\ for one \ in a path or using @ give the same result. I edited my answer. Check if you agree with it.